# Seeking Software to Convert Line Drawings into Connect-the-Dots Puzzles

Tags: puzzle-creation, pencil-and-paper-games, reference-request

I am on the lookout for a software solution, whether free or premium, that is capable of transforming line drawing images into connect-the-dots puzzles. My interest lies in both vector and bitmap formats for the original images. The ideal software would automatically analyze the drawing and generate a numbered puzzle that guides the user in recreating the image by connecting dots in a sequence.

Specific Requirements:

- Input Compatibility: The software should accept input images in vector (e.g., SVG) or bitmap (e.g., PNG, JPEG) formats.
- Automation: A key feature is the automatic conversion of these drawings into puzzles, ideally without requiring extensive manual intervention to designate dots or sequences.
- Output Format: Information on the output format of the puzzles (e.g., PDF, interactive web format) would also be appreciated.
- User Experience: If possible, insights into the user-friendliness and accessibility of the software for educators or artists would be valuable.
- Context: As an educator looking to create engaging educational materials, I believe connect-the-dots puzzles derived from educational diagrams or artworks could be a novel way to enhance learning and interest in various subjects.

Does anyone know of software that meets these criteria or have any recommendations based on similar needs?

Comment: A quick google search reveals plenty of offerings such as [Connect the Dots Generator](https://www.ohmydots.com/creator.html). What you have you already found? Why don't you like them?

Comment: this one i've missed. I will make a try! thanks!